# Sending and receiving progress monitoring in socket asynchronous

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, progress-bar

I saw examples of asynchronous socket server here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx#Y0

How do I know the total of bytes that are currently being received and the total of bytes that is currently being sent by the server and display that to progress bar? Thank You.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

// State object for reading client data asynchronously
public class StateObject {
    // Client  socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener {
    // Thread signal.
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public static void StartListening() {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // The DNS name of the computer
        // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true) {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept( 
                new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener );

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
            state.buffer,0,bytesRead));

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
            // more data.
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) {
                // All the data has been read from the 
                // client. Display it on the console.
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                content.Length, content );
                // Echo the data back to the client.
                Send(handler, content);
            } else {
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data) {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
        new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
        try {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }


    public static int Main(String[] args) {
        StartListening();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TCP protocol does not specify the message size, you have to do this within the payload that you are sending.

You could prepend the data length to the the data that you are sending down the pipe and read this as on receipt of the first chunk of data.  This will then give you the total data size which you can use to calculate the percentage read, which you can display as a progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

This is a lot of code and I am not going to read it.

The Socket class does not remember how many bytes you have written to it and how many bytes came out of it. You can track that yourself in two variables of type long.

If you want to know how many bytes are currently queued, you can find out using the Socket.Available property for the receive queue. For the send queue you cannot find out.